# Dynamically generate SCSS classes for padding and margins not working

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to dynamically generate automatic margin and paddings in SCSS but it is not working. It seems like something is wrong with the #{spacing} part, but I have no clue what is actually generating this error.

I've got this SCSS code:

```
@each $abbr, $name in ("t": "top", "r": "right", "b": "bottom", "l": "left") {
    @each $spacing in $spaceamounts {
      .m#{$abbr}-#{$spacing} {
        margin-#{$name}: $spacing rem;
      }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Expected identifier.
  ┌──> src\assets\main.scss
29│       .m#{$abbr}-#{$spacing} {
  │                    ^^^^^^^^ 
  ╵
  ╷
1 │ .mt-0.5 
  │       ━ error in interpolated output
  ╵
  src\assets\main.scss 29:20  root stylesheet
```

Comment: You can read that the generated class contains a dot `.`, it comes from the `$spacing`variable.

Comment: In addition to the dot causing an error you need to define the `$spaceamounts` map. You also need to interpolate `#{spacing}` in `margin-#{$name}: #{spacing}rem`.